# Reference/Dereference Identities

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dereference, inverse

When x is a L-value (let's say a variable), then the following identity holds:

x == *(&x)

This is quite easy to explain, because &x is a pointer to x and the dereference operator * applied to &x will then of course return x.

Now I am wondering if the converse makes sense. To be precise I am wondering if

p == &(*p)

when p is a non-dangling pointer.
This seems to make sense, because *p is itself a L-value (a value which has an adress), because we already have the pointer (=adress) p to it. So you only need to know, that such pointers are unique, because then &(*p) has no other chance as to be p.

So when both identities are true you can say, that, mathematically, * and & are inverse functions of one another.

Am I correct? Are there any possible exceptions to this alleged rules?

Comment: If `p` is not a pointer, you can't do `&(*p)`.

Comment: ...but question already states, "when p is a non-dangling pointer."

Comment: Maybe "adjoint functors" would be a better term than "inverses", since the two operate on different kinds of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `p` is an object pointer, `&*p` is equivalent to `p`. The evaluation of `*p` doesn't occur and this is guaranteed by the C Standard.

```
char *q, *p = NULL;
q = &*p;  // equivalent to q = p;
```

Here is the relevant paragraph of the Standard:

> (C99, 6.5.3.2p3) "If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue."

**EDIT**:  After @ldav1s comment, I changed the word *pointer* to *object pointer*. Indeed if `p` is of type `void *`, then `&*p` is invalid. For information, this has been discussed by the C Committee in Defect Report #102: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_012.html

Comment: +1. However `p` cannot be a `void *`, since it's not allowed to dereference a `void *`.

Comment: @ldav1s agree, `p` cannot be a `void *` I edited my answer for *object pointer* instead of *pointer*.

Comment: Very nice answer. I find it interesting that &*p is itself not a L-value, so you can't do something like q = &(&*p); but q = &p; is no problem. May the rationale behind this be, that at least in theory *p could be a copy of the value behind p, so that the adress of this copy is different from p itself? Or am I overthinking and not making any sense?

Comment: @Anthales the result of the `&` operator is actually never a lvalue, so it makes sense that `&*p` is not a lvalue even if `p` is a lvalue.

Comment: @ouah yeah you are right, my comment was confused - I was really thinking about what would happen without the equivalence of &*p to p (for example when compiling with the non-C99 compliant MSVC) and I'm guessing the result would be random, or maybe a stack adress.